# Remove NavigationView close icon SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

[image: This is the icon] How do I remove this icon?

I am using very simple code; just navigation view

Comment: Show us the code that you are using, FYI that icon is `sidebar` icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @**Nirav D**, this button is used to toggle the sidebar visibility.

### **iOS 16 & above**

In **iOS 16**, **Apple** gave **Navigation** a big refresh:

1. Introducing [`NavigationStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack)*(which is probably what you want)*, it is used to present a view allowing the user to navigate using [`NavigationLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) as you would on an **iPhone**.
2. Introducing [`NavigationSplitView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview)*(which is what you’re seing in the simulator right now)*, it is used to present a menu *(sidebar)* that can present detail views. You can have up to 3 columns.
3. Deprecating [`NavigationView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview), from now on you have to use the above containers as `NavigationView` will be obsoleted in a future **iOS** release.

### **iOS 15 & below**

In versions earlier than 16, you have to use `NavigationView`. `NavigationView` accepts [`navigationViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationviewstyle(_:)), the default style on **iPhone** is [`StackNavigationViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationviewstyle) where the content is presented in one column. However, on **iPad** in order to maximise the use of screen estate, **SwiftUI** sets the default style to [`ColumnNavigationViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationviewstyle) that presents the content in columns (Master -> Detail…).

- If you mean to use a single column: you must use either `NavigationStack` or `NaigationView` with `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)`;
- If you have to use multiple columns & still hide the button: use `.navigationBarHidden(true)` on the sidebar view, or `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)` for **iOS 16+**.

For more info, check: [Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigation) & [The SwiftUI cookbook for navigation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10054/)

Comment: Instead of hiding whole navigationBar, I would like to just replace the sidebar button with my own designed button. How I could achieve that? Or how I can achieve same functionality of sidebar button? Please let me know if any option available.